# How to make a Canvas part of a view in android?

Tags: android, image, canvas

I am working on a code which has the canvas for touch,but the code is in separate one & I want canvas to be part of an xml which comprises of other imageview and others.This is my code

```
public class Tutorial2D extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(new Panel(this));
}
```

}

This is the other part

```
public class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

private ViewThread mThread;
private ArrayList<Element> mElements = new ArrayList<Element>();

public Panel(Context context) {
    super(context);
    getHolder().addCallback(this);
    mThread = new ViewThread(this);
}

public void doDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    synchronized (mElements) {
        for (Element element : mElements) {
            element.doDraw(canvas);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (!mThread.isAlive()) {
        mThread = new ViewThread(this);
        mThread.setRunning(true);
        mThread.start();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (mThread.isAlive()) {
        mThread.setRunning(false);
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    synchronized (mElements) {
        mElements.add(new Element(getResources(), (int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY()));
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

}

How to make the canvas part of the xml,any snippet on this will be greatly helpful.Thanks